# Selecting distance-based features using ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, modelbuilder

I have a shapefile file of rows and I need to make a selection based on distance, how to execute this select command automatically?

I need to select and export to a new layer the feature with greater distance.

I want to use ModelBuilder for this!

I use Arcgis 10.3.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  What does your model so far look like?